# Create Teams one-on-one Chat via Service Principal

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'd like to use this api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

To create a Teams one-on-one Chat. However I see that under "Permission type". "Application" is not supported.

Does this mean service principals or azure ad applications can't create chats? I would have thought that under the applications api permissions I can just add "Delegated"?

However when I try this via postman. I get an error saying `Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.`, only when I use the token from the service principal. But, if I use my own access token from the graph explorer it works.

So now I'm wondering if it's even possible with a service principal? In the end I'd like to know how to do this with postman, and eventually powershell.

Comment: As per the documentation, this endpoint does not support Application Permissions because the chat must must be done on behalf of a user. I also don't think you can do this through the service principal.

Comment: I think you can create chat by an Application now on [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686#permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Currently create chat using application permission is not supported. You need to use the delegated permissions to create a chat inside teams. This is by design. when you use graph explorer Auth token the token consists of delegated permissions. Could you please check the permissions using jwt.io for the auth token.

Comment: Is your answer still apply? The latest doc seems already support `Application` permission type. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686#permissions